# SOAP is Simple Object Access Protocol or Service Oriented Application Platform?

Tags: c#, java, .net, wcf, soap

Are they the same thing? does that Service Oriented Application Platform use Simple Object Access Protocol? not clear to me.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just an acronym that represents more than one thing.

Comment: How's this even a technically objective question? Just google SOAP acronyms.

Comment: SOAP always was a protocol to me. SOA always was Service Oriented Architecture. SOAP as "Service Oriented Application Platform" I believe you wanna talk about SOA.

Comment: Well, one is a platform and the other a protocol so they can't be the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

["Statistically" speaking](http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=%22simple+object+access+protocol%22&word2=%22service+oriented+application+platform%22), SOAP refers to Simple Object Access Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I learned SOAP first as the former (simple object access protocol), from about the year 2000 onwards I think from memory with ROPE (remote object proxy engine) - I'm not certain that was an in-joke (SOAP on a ROPE).

This [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) seems to support the idea that the acronym now represents different meanings, although I suspect that the original definition is still valid.  This [article](http://www.xmlfiles.com/articles/adam/soapsoup/default.asp) seems noteworthy also.

I actually haven't heard of SOAP as "Service Oriented Architecture Platform" before, usually it's just SOA, so that might be leading to some confusion.

..c'mon, how about a +1 for "soap on a rope"?  :)

Comment: I think you're looking for the [disambiguation link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soap_(disambiguation)).

Comment: Oh I was referencing this sentiment: "SOAP once stood for 'Simple Object Access Protocol' but this acronym was dropped with Version 1.2 of the standard"